# Python DF issue. Match on the basis of column value

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, string-matching, pandas-loc

I have a DF which is quite big. A snippet like the one shown below.

[image]

```
SrNo | Merchant | Revenue | Currency

1    | UBER SR  | 123     | INR

2    | UBER (SR)| 123     | INR

3    | SR UBER  | 123     | INR

4    | ZOMATO SR| 123     | INR

5    | ZOMATOSR | 123     | INR

6    |12FLIPAKRT| 123     | INR

7    | FLIPKART | 123     | INR
```

My Output should look like:

```
SrNo | Merchant | Revenue | Currency |Merchant_Flag

1    | UBER SR  | 123     | INR      | UBER

2    | UBER (SR)| 123     | INR      | UBER

3    | SR UBER  | 123     | INR      | UBER

4    | ZOMATO SR| 123     | INR      | ZOMATO

5    | ZOMATOSR | 123     | INR      | ZOMATO

6    |12FLIPAKRT| 123     | INR      | FLIPKART

7    | FLIPKART | 123     | INR      | FLIPKART
```

Explanation : I want to add an additional column which should have values wrt to Merchant column i.e. if the Merchant column value has UBER in it, Merchant_Flag should be UBER and likewise for other ZOMATO, FLIPKART.

My Dataset is huge. I tried using re.search and then .replace using if and else for my conditions, it is giving me performance issue.
Another solution, I tried was using .loc

`df.loc[df['columnname'].str.contains('')]`. Not sure how to proceed. Can someone help on this.

Comment: what are you using `pyspark` or `pandas` and how do you suppose spelling errors should be handled? `i.e 12FLIPAKRT` won't be picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) method, it is always (as a rule of thumb) better in terms of performance to use built-in methods when performing iterative operations over an object instead of coding a plain for/while loop in python. This way you get rid of the overhead of calling the `pandas.DataFrame.loc` accessor multiple times.

```py
import re # import regex matching

df = pd.DataFrame({"Merchant":["UBER SR", "SR UBER", "ZOMATO SR", "12FLIPKART"]})

# Use applymap to quickly iterate over the whole dataframe
df["Merchant_Flag"] = df.applymap(lambda x: re.search(r"UBER|ZOMATO|FLIPKART", x).group(0))
```

(**Note:** `.group(0)` is used to select the first match of [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search))

Output:

```
     Merchant Merchant_Flag
0     UBER SR          UBER
1     SR UBER          UBER
2   ZOMATO SR        ZOMATO
3  12FLIPKART      FLIPKART
```

---

##### EDIT

In case you don't know all the merchants' names, you will need to modify a little bit the function passed to `applymap`:

```py
import re # import regex matching

# Function definition
def match_merchant(elem, reg):
    # Match 
    m = re.search(reg, elem)
    if m != None:
        # Return first match if we got a match
        return m.group(0)
    else:
        # Here you may specify exactly what it is you want to return: None, empty String...
        return None 
    
df = pd.DataFrame({"Merchant":["UBER SR",
                               "SR UBER",
                               "ZOMATO SR",
                               "12FLIPKART",
                               "CABIFY"]})

# Merchants you want to match
regex = r"UBER|ZOMATO|FLIPKART"

# Use applymap to quickly iterate over the whole dataframe
df["Merchant_Flag"] = df.applymap(lambda x: match_merchant(x, regex))
```

Output:

```py
     Merchant Merchant_Flag
0     UBER SR          UBER
1     SR UBER          UBER
2   ZOMATO SR        ZOMATO
3  12FLIPKART      FLIPKART
4      CABIFY          None
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. However it is giving me an error as mentioned below :- ----> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: Sure, could you tell me exactly where is that error occurring? Is it with my code or when using your DataFrame? Perhaps I should add that, given that you have more than one column, you should first select the column ```Merchant``` before applying ```.applymap```, like this: ```df["Merchant_Flag"] = df[["Merchant"]].applymap(lambda x: re.search(r"UBER|ZOMATO|FLIPKART", x).group(0))```

Comment: If I just run your code as it is, it works fine. But when I am using it on my DF, it is giving me this error.

Comment: If I just run your code as it is, it works fine. But when I am using it on my DF, it is giving me this error. Yes I have used on a particular column only. I am using the below code **df=pd.read_csv("myfile.csv") **and df[["Merchant_Name"]].applymap(lambda x: re.search(r"UBER|ZOMATO|FLIPKART", x).group(0)) . Error :  pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
<ipython-input-14-141dbf22e57c> in <lambda>(x)----> 1 df2["Merchant_Flag"] = df2[["Merchant_Name"]].applymap(lambda x: re.search(r"UBER|ZOMATO|FLIPKART", x).group(0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: This means that ```re.search``` did not match any of the merchants in the regular expression. Do you have any other merchants? if so you should include them all in the ```r"UBER|ZOMATO|FLIPKART"``` regex. If you don't know all the merchants the function passed on to ```applymap``` should be modified to handle the special case when no match occurs, is that your case?

Comment: Yes I am aware of the merchants. It worked for me. Thanks for the help. Appreciated

Comment: In case of pyspark, applymap is not useful. What can you suggest for big datasets in pyspark.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what merchants could exist, then you could use something like this:

```
merchants = ['UBER', 'ZOMATO', 'FLIPKART']

for merchant in merchants:
    df.loc[df["Merchant"].str.contains(merchant), "Merchant_Flag"] = merchant
```

Comment: @AnukritiSingh Glad it did. If you could, please pick my answer as correct. It would mean a lot to me. :)